# upload public file gdrive api and get public link

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

Hi I am developing a web application with GDrive api in javascript.

In my page I can upload a file to the GDrive folder of the logged person.

What I want is that the file is public access to other user with a link to download the file.

```
 var reader = new FileReader();
 reader.readAsBinaryString(fileData);
 reader.onload = function(e) {
      var contentType = fileData.type || 'application/octet-stream';
      var metadata = {
        'title': fileData.name,
        'mimeType': contentType
      };
      var body = {
        'value': 'google account',
        'type': 'anyone',
        'role': 'reader'
      };
      var base64Data = btoa(reader.result);
      var multipartRequestBody =
          delimiter +
          'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
          JSON.stringify(metadata) +
          delimiter +
          'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
          'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
          '\r\n' +
          base64Data +
          close_delim;

      var request = gapi.client.request({
          'path': '/upload/drive/v2/files',
          'method': 'POST',
          'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart'},
          'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
          },
          'body': multipartRequestBody});
      if (!callback) {
        callback = function(file) {
          console.log(file)
        };
      }
      request.execute(callback);
    };
```

Comment: I found an option to set permissions after uploading the file. I copy the code below. Now the problem I have is that gapi.client.drive undefined.  `var resource = {
          'value': 'default',
          'type': 'anyone',
          'role': 'reader'
        };
        var request = gapi.client.drive.permissions.insert({
          'fileId': file.id,
          'resource': resource
        }).execute(function() { 
          alert("file set to public")
        });`

Comment: Thanks for sharing, were you able to find out how to do this during upload API call? Rather then in consequent/second API call?